# Why do my results become un-reproducible when run from qsub?

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, qsub

I'm running matlab on a cluster. when i run my .m script from an interactive matlab session on the cluster my results are reproducible. but when i run the same script from a qsub command, as part of an array job away from my watchful eye, I get believable but unreproducible results. The .m files are doing exactly the same thing, including saving the results as .mat files.

Anyone know why run one way the scripts give reproducible results, and run the other way they become unreproducible?

Is this only a problem with reproducibility or is this indicative of inaccurate results?

%%%%%
Thanks to spuder for a helpful answer. Just in case anyone stumbles upon this and is interested here is some further information.
If you use more than one thread in Matlab jobs, this may result in stealing resources from other jobs which plays havoc with the results. So you have 2 options:
1. Select exclusive access to a node. The cluster I am using is not currently allowing parallel array jobs, so doing this for me was very wasteful - i took a whole node but used it in serial. 
2. Ask matlab to run on a singleCompThread. This may make your script take longer to complete, but it gets jobs through the queue faster.

Comment: ok a bit out of my depth here with the lingo. but it is embarrassingly parallel so i am running each script in serial, without using parallel computation. does that make a difference?

Comment: In terms of the inputs or outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of variables at play. Ruling out transient issues such as network performance, and load here are a couple of possible explanations:

You are getting assigned a different batch of nodes when you run an interactive job from when you use qsub.

I've seen some sites that assign a policy of 'exclusive' to the nodes that run interactive jobs and 'shared' to nodes that run queued 'qsub' jobs. If that is the case, then you will almost always see better performance on the exclusive nodes.

Another answer might be that the interactive jobs are assigned to nodes that have less network congestion.

Additionally, if you are requesting multiple nodes, and you happen to land on nodes that traverse multiple hops, then you could be seeing significant network slowdowns. The solution would be for the cluster administrator to setup nodesets.

Are you using multiple nodes for the job? How are you requesting the resources?

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the enhanced performance on the interactive job vs the qsub jobs, I have noticed that. I do not request exclusive nodes, although I've just read that Matlab threads require exclusive nodes. You're definitely on to something, I don't understand how this impacts reproducibility though?

Comment: Although actually my job isn't multi-threaded so exclusive nodes shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: This appears to give reproducible results if scripts are re-run via qsub. However, the results remain different to those from interactive matlab sessions. Can somebody please clarify for me, if you don't request exclusive access to a node when using qsub, does that mean your script will be running on different nodes EVEN if there is no parallelisation in  your script?? Why else would non-exclusivity cause non-reproducibility?

Comment: It depends on which scheduler you are using. (I'm familiar with Moab/Maui & Torque). These schedulers by default will find the most efficient grouping of processors, even if they aren't on the same node.

Comment: It is the Torque batch queueing system with Moab scheduler. So it doesn't matter that my script is serial, and I haven't requested threads, it will still run it in parallel on different processors?

Comment: It does seem to work so thank you so much spuder. The only problem is that requesting exclusive access to a node reduces the throughput / makes my jobs stay in the queue longer

Comment: Depending on how you submitted the job, you may be allocated multiple processors on different nodes. It is up to matlab to decide to take advantage of those multiple processors. In your situation, it sounds like you are only using 1 processor on one node.

Comment: That is the down side to 'exclusive', it often does take longer for the jobs to start.

Comment: In which case I am confused as to how this is fixing the problem. Do you think it is because the jobs are going through more slowly, so the data races that High Performance Mark was talking about are no longer an issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44065/discussion-between-user1792403-and-spuder)